# Is there a way to select every other line of faces along a cylinder quickly?

Tags: edges, selection-tools, select, loop

Is there a way to select like in the picture but quickly? and without having to select line by line?

I found a tutorial but it says to select the edges, I would like to select the faces.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar picks up *all* matches to an existing selection, which makes this sort of thing possible:

[image]

1.<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> Select Next Active

2.<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select Similar > Normal

Comment: Good solution in this case. I just didn't take the "similar normal" option to make it a more general approach. If the cylinder for example was in an object containing more meshes, the similar normal might select other faces as well which are not part of the cylinder (unless you hide the rest).

Comment: Hi, @Gordon! Of course! Hence my care in the wording, not to suggest this method is any way 'correct', Yours is.  If  available, though, it's the sort of thing my muscle-memory reaches for, to be quick.

Answer (score 5):

The following method works with e.g. a cylinder like in your question. For more complex shapes with more varying angles between the adjacent faces this might not work (especially the last step *Linked Flat Faces*).

1. Select one row of faces by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking on the vertical edge between two faces.

   [image: select horizontal row]
2. From the menu bar choose *Select* > *Checker Deselect*.

   [image: checker deselect]
3. Now that only every second face in the row is selected, choose *Select Linked* > *Linked Flat Faces*.

   [image: linked flat faces]

   Now every second column of faces is selected. In the bottom left you have an option called *Sharpness* to which angle adjacent faces should be taken into account, the default 1° should be okay for this task.

   [image: sharpness setting]